# Non-included navigation properties and db round-trips

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Let's say I have this line:

```
var eggs = db.Nests.Single(b => b.id = 20).Birds.FirstOrDefault().Eggs;
```

In my profiler trace, I see there are multiple commands being executed:

```
SQL:BatchString
SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[id]
...
FROM [dbo].[Nest] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 20 = [Extent1].[id]
SQL:BatchCompleted

RPC:Completed
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
...
FROM [dbo].[Bird] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[NesId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=20

RPC:Completed
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
...
FROM [dbo].[Egg] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[BirdId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=13
```

Are all those commands being executed within the same request, or is there a round-trip for each of these?

Furthermore, can I get confirmation that this is the most efficient way to write the above:

```
var eggs = db.Nests.Include("Birds")
           .Single(b => b.id = 20)
           .Birds.Include("Eggs")
           .FirstOrDefault()
           .Eggs;
```

Or would an explicit join be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it's perfectly normal that you get multiple queries in your first example. Unless you use `Include()` as in your second example, accessing any navigation property generates a new SQL query.

I'm not sure how your db schema is laid out but assuming `Birds` has a foreign key to `Nests` called `Id_Nest` you could rewrite this query as:

```
var eggs = db.Birds.Include("Eggs")
                   .First(x => x.Id_Nest == 20)
                   .Eggs
                   .ToList();
```

The `Include()` generates about the same code as an explicit `join` so no need to worry about the code being different. And as for round-trips, if you mean round trips between the web server and the database , then yes, there is probably a round trip for each query. It's not a huge deal if the connection stays open though. But it is preferable to get everything you need in one go via `join` or `Include()` rather than hitting the db 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you described in your question is a typical example of the [lazy-loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) feature that helps quickly building code that *works*, but executes *poorly* because performances are far from optimal. As a side note, I personally always recommend to completely deactivate lazy-loading.

> Are all those commands being executed within the same request, or is
>   there a round-trip for each of these?

Yes, there is one round trip for each request. In your example that's probably not a big deal, but imagine your code is inside a loop... You multiply the number of requests you have (3) by the number of iterations. You can end up with literally thousands of requests.

> Furthermore, can I get confirmation that this is the most efficient
>   way to write the above:

That's not the most efficient way to write your query. Actually it probably won't even compile (you cannot use `Include` as you did).

As a general recommendation, **the most efficient way is to include all the navigation properties you need, then, and only then, to execute the query** using a single `ToList`/`Single`/`First` or whatever function that actually executes the query and materializes the entities. So you only have one SQL request.

For the specific example you gave, @Radu Porumb suggestion is probably the query that'll produce the most simple/efficient SQL. Of course, you'll have to verify this assumption using a profiler.

Comment: Glimpse is probably a better option here